# Launching a program and retrieving its standard streams later

Tags: ssh, services, stdin

I want to be able to start some specific servers (related to a game) on a my VPS (to which I connect through ssh). This is simple, I just connect and execute the command, but this creates some problems.

What I would like to do is:

- launch it in a way that doesn't depend on SSH (eg. I don't want it to close when I close the SSH session)
- be able to retrieve the stdin/stdout of the process (this because I can send commands through stdin, but once lost I don't exactly know how I'm supposed to get it back and keep using it)

I think there are many solutions out there which would be a simple and efficient for my problem (without looking for anything too complex)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU Screen would be an easy choice.

- Open new screen session with the `screen` command
- Execute desired commands
- Detatch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- Exit SSH

Next time you need to reconnect to the screen session, simply run `screen -r` (resume). If you expect a lot of output, you may want to redirect STDOUT and STDERR to a file in the screen session.

Comment: quite straightforward to use and functional.. thanks, this will be useful!

Comment: @Jack you're most welcome!